Redirect URI Not Preserved Post-Login
I have a flow that works through Azure B2C when my app is hosted in IIS; however, it's failing now that I've moved it to an App Service.
From the below screenshot you can see that I initially land on my page fine (i.e. - Login.aspx), then bounce through the B2C while it does its magic, and then get delivered back to my page with the id_token JWT as part of the payload (payload not shown). But from there the wheels fall off - I ingest the JWT fine, but then as you can see the Location Header in the Response Headers collection is for the Azure platform instead of the intranet-facing App Gateway URI which is the façade in front of it. As a result of that misdirection the browser 302s to the wrong place and I get a 403 error instead of the content I expect. The redirect_uri I pass from the first page is correct (not shown), and the Request URL on the page highlighted is also the value I expect so I think (?) the Redirect URIs are setup properly in the B2C.
I say the JWT gets ingested fine because if I subsequently paste the proper URI into the browser's address bar the page renders fine - it's just when the code tries to take it there when the session is initially being built it fails.
I imagine I'm missing a setting somewhere, or support for a redirect in the code, but I'm not sure where to look as this stuff is new to me and I've inherited this project.


Check if this helps https://trycatchdebug.net/news/1220487/flow-in-azure-app-service-redirect-uri-issue

Cool and thanks, @Sridevi. There is some promise in the article, but I think I can rule out some of the scenarios it mentions because I do get back to may app okay after the AAD step ... things just go sideways after my app ingests the JWT. I'll have a look and report back here.
